# Rearrange csv.file

Tags: c#, string, streamreader

I want to rearrange my Text file.
Here is my data of my Text File as below

11;12;13;14;15;

1;2;3;4;5;

I want arrange it become as below

11=1

12=2

13=3

14=4

15=5

error message = The file could not be read:
Index was outside the bounds of the array.

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), describe your problem and make an honest attempt if you expect to receive a reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have already read file using `File.ReadAllLines()` method. it stores each line as a single element of the list. Now to transform `;` separated line to the given format you can try below code,

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(<csv file path>);
var firstLine = lines[0].Split(new string[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var secondLine = lines[1].Split(new string[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var listLength = Math.Min(firstLine.Lenght, secondLine.Length);
for(var i = 0; i < listLength; i++)
    Console.WriteLine($"{firstLine[i]}={secondLine[i]}"); //Instead of console print you can store it in CSV
```

Comment: You could also use Enumerable.Zip instead of Min & loop.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution using [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-5.0)

```
var lines = str.Split(Environment.NewLine,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); // or read from File
var keys = lines[0].Split(';',StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var values = lines[1].Split(';',StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, keys.Zip(values,(k,v)=>$"{k}={v}")); // Store result in file if needed
```

Comment: cool, yeah if someone wants to do it with Linq, then Enumerable.Zip will be a good solution